# How to monitor replication progress for a Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring, replication

I have a Kafka topic that somehow went from 3 ISRs to 1 ISR, in a kafka cluster with 3 brokers. I changed minimum ISR from 2 to 1 to allow it to function. Presumably the other brokers are trying to replicate the topic from the leader, how can I monitor their progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can monitor those metrics to see the replication lag:

```
kafka.server:type=FetcherLagMetrics,name=ConsumerLag,clientId=([-.\w]+),topic=([-.\w]+),partition=([0-9]+)

Lag in number of messages per follower replica. This is useful to know if the replica is slow or has stopped replicating from the leader.
```

As stated in https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/

Yannick